# How to monitor network status in android

Tags: android, networking

hey i am new in android please anyone help me.
I just wanted to know the names of libraries that enables me  to monitor network connectivity.

Comment: Please narrow down your question. Do you want to know if the devices is connected to the internet or not ? Or something else ?

Comment: You are searching for the api: ConnectivityManager:  
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is not clear! 
If checking the network connection is what you want, the following will do.

```
// Check network connection
private boolean isNetworkConnected(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();    
}
```

Comment: sorry actually i just want a generic library that enables me to check network status periodically that i can easily implement in any project

Answer (score 25):

Just create a `broadcast receiver` with `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` action. And you will get a `broadcast` whenever network connectivity will change.

**NetworkUtil.java**

```
public class NetworkUtil {

    public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
    public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
    public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


    public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                return TYPE_WIFI;

            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return TYPE_MOBILE;
        } 
        return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }

    public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
        int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
        String status = null;
        if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
            status = "Wifi enabled";
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            status = "Mobile data enabled";
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            status = "Not connected to Internet";
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

**Broadcast Receiver to handle changes in Network state**

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);

        Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
<application  ...>
     ...
        <receiver
            android:name="net.viralpatel.network.NetworkChangeReceiver"
            android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
      ...
</application>
```

**UPDATE**

**Permissions required to access network state:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: sorry for stupid question but how can i use this in my project

Comment: You can get the full instruction how to implement the here http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/

Comment: hey i've tried this but every time it shows me toast "Not connected to Internet" actually the problem is

Comment: ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();         is not working

Comment: You need to add ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission in AndroidMenifest. Check my updated answer.

Comment: when i turn wifi on activeNetwork object doesn't get initialized also when i turn data connection on in 2G mode activeNetwork get initialized but doesn't match with constant "ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE"

Comment: yeah i've mentioned ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission in AndroidMenifest

Comment: i think there is something wrong with the  <intent-filter>
             
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                
            </intent-filter>

Comment: This method will not work for API above 24, use context registered broadcast for better solution

Answer (score 9):

A small class for kotlin, which supports monitoring the status of the Internet before and after the 24 (Andoird P) version of sdk. Just create/inject this class and add an observer. In the comments version without LiveData.

```
class ConnectivityListener(private val context: Context) {

    val isConnected = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    //region used on api < 24
    private val intentFilter by lazy {
        IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)
    }

    private val networkBroadcastReceiver by lazy {
        object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                val isConn = isConnected()
                isConnected.postValue(isConn)
            }
        }
    }
    //endregion

    private val networkCallback by lazy {
        object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                isConnected.postValue(true)
            }

            override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                isConnected.postValue(false)
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            getConnectivityManager()?.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
        } else {
            context.registerReceiver(networkBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter)
        }
    }

    fun isConnected(): Boolean {
        val activeNetwork = getConnectivityManager()?.activeNetworkInfo
        val isConnected = activeNetwork?.isConnectedOrConnecting == true
        return isConnected
    }

    fun getConnectivityManager() = getSystemService(context, ConnectivityManager::class.java)
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zakrodionov/04bc52cb2c2f0aaba5c12a4b6da2575b

Answer (score 5):

`ConnectivityManager.CONNECTION_ACTION` is deprecated on Android P, so you'll have to use a combination of solutions based on API level.

First declare the following permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

```
enum class InternetConnectionStatus {
  CONNECTED,
  DISCONNECTED
}
```

I put the following code in my Application class to avoid being affected by configuration changes.

```
private var connectionStatusSubject: BehaviorSubject<InternetConnectionStatus> =
    BehaviorSubject.create()


fun observeNetworkChanges() {
    // getSystemService() is the core-ktx version
    val connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager? = getSystemService()
    if (
        BUILD.VERSION.SDK_INT >= BUILD.VERSION_CODES.P &&
        connectivityManager != null
    ) {
      val callback = NetworkChangeCallback(connectionStatusSubject, connectivityManager)
      connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(callback)
    } else {
      val networkChangeBroadcastReceiver =
        NetworkChangeBroadcastReceiver(connectionStatusSubject)
      val filter = IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)
      registerReceiver(networkChangeBroadcastReceiver, filter)
    }
  }
```

```
// API P+
class NetworkChangeCallback(
  private val subject: BehaviorSubject<InternetConnectionStatus>,
  connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager
) : NetworkCallback() {

  init {
    val network: Network? = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
    if (network == null) {
      subject.onNext(DISCONNECTED)
    } else {
      val capabilities: NetworkCapabilities? = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
      if (capabilities?.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) == true) {
        subject.onNext(CONNECTED)
      } else {
        subject.onNext(DISCONNECTED)
      }
    }
  }

  override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
    subject.onNext(CONNECTED)
  }

  override fun onLost(network: Network) {
    subject.onNext(DISCONNECTED)
  }
}
```

```
// Below API P
class NetworkChangeBroadcastReceiver(
  private val subject: BehaviorSubject<InternetConnectionStatus>
) : BroadcastReceiver() {
  override fun onReceive(
    context: Context,
    intent: Intent
  ) {
    val noConnectivity: Boolean = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false)
    if (noConnectivity) {
      subject.onNext(DISCONNECTED)
    } else {
      subject.onNext(CONNECTED)
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using RxJava and a `BehaviorSubject` to turn network status into an `Observable`, but you can just as easily replace this with a callback with something like

```
interface NetworkChangedListener {
  fun onConnected()
  fun onDisconnected()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check network status.. First create this class..

```
    public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context _context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
    this._context = context;
}

public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null) 
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null) 
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
}
```

}

Then whenever you want to check status..

```
ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext()); 
Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
    (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Should check if you currently have connectivity

http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

Try out below method to get the Network status.

`ConnectivityManager Class`

The primary responsibilities of this class are to:

- Monitor network connections (Wi-Fi, GPRS, UMTS, etc.)
- Send broadcast intents when network connectivity changes
- Attempt to "fail over" to another network when connectivity to a network is lost
- Provide an API that allows applications to query the coarse-grained or fine-grained state of the available networks

> ```
>    public static boolean IsNetConnected() {
>     boolean NetConnected = false;
>     try {
>         ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) m_context
>                 .getSystemService(m_context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
>         if (connectivity == null) {
>             NetConnected = false;
>         } else {
>             NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
>             if (info != null) {
>                 for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
>                     if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
>                         NetConnected = true;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>         NetConnected = false;
>     }
>     return NetConnected;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since in typical Android apps, we will need to check if the user is connected to the internet, so make a utility class with all these functions and pass in context like below:

```
package utilities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class Util {
    public boolean isNetworkConnected(Context c){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
                = (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();    
    }
}
```

And you can call it by:

```
Util utility = new Util();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"State is :"+utility.isNetworkConnected(this), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** `getActiveNetworkInfo()` was deprecated in Android 10. Use `NetworkCallbacks` instead for apps that target Android 10 (API level 29) and higher.

---

**CONNECTIVITY_ACTION**
This constant was deprecated in API level 28. apps should use the more versatile `requestNetwork(NetworkRequest, PendingIntent)`, `registerNetworkCallback(NetworkRequest, PendingIntent)` or `registerDefaultNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)` functions instead for faster and more detailed updates about the network changes they care about.

Answer (score -1):

For the above answers which uses
   `networkUtils.getConnectivityStatusString(context)`  is returning false just add this line in **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<application
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
 ......
 ......
```

Comment: @Sergio could you please explain why and best alternate solution?